# Java | Webservice error

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I'm trying to create a jax-ws client for a service built some time ago. While I creating the client (using myecplise's ws-client creation tool) I'm getting a error that halt the creation of ws client the error was:

```
AXIS error
No service is available at this URL
```

I'm not familiar with webservices, I just configured it on myecplise and added the context path to the tomcat's config file (server.xml). Also since the written service is an old one I'm not sure about the url.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that your URL is wrong. Try a different one. See the Axis docs for some examples what it might look like. Check some code which uses the service and check the config files of the server on which your service runs.